# Azure DevOps: How do I expand variables in a template in the YML file referring to that template for use in a conditional?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have two Azure DevOps .yml-based templates, one referring to another.  I'm finding that variables specified in the one being referred to do not expand when I need them to in a conditional in the template referring to that template.  Here is how they look:

Parent template:

```yaml
  jobs:
 

          
      - deployment:
        displayName: Release
   
        variables:
        - template: variables.yml
 
        environment: 
            name: QA
            resourceType: VirtualMachine
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
            
        ...

          #this copies to xxMaster
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            #condition:  eq('${{ parameters.appName }}', 'all') 
            condition:   and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'),  eq('${{ configuration }}', '$(productionConfiguration)'))
            inputs:  
                SourceFolder: 'C:\DevOps\$(Build.BuildNumber)\Content\D_C\a\1\s\xxTexas\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' 
                Contents: '**\*.*'
                OverWrite: true
                TargetFolder: 'C:\Production\Web Sites\xxMaster'
```

Child Template:

```yaml
variables:
  - name: solution
    value: '**/*.sln'
  - name: buildPlatform
    value: 'Any CPU'
  - name: buildConfiguration
    value: "${{ parameters.configuration }}"
  - name: productionConfiguration
    value: 'Horsie'
```

In this case, when the conditional should work and ${{ configuration }} equals 'Horsie', the YAML is evaluated and comes up with

and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'), eq('Horsie', '$(productionConfiguration)'))

That is, $(productionConfiguration), the variable specified in the referred-to template, is never expanded into 'Horsie.'  What should I do to make it so the variable from that sub-template is expanded and my conditional works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your YAML sample, the cause of this issue is the format of the variable:`$(productionConfiguration)` in condition.

You need to use the format: `variables['productionConfiguration']` to call the pipeline variable.

Here is an example:

```
stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    variables:
     - template: template.yml
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 'smarthotel-dev'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world
            condition:   and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'),  eq('${{ configuration }}', variables['productionConfiguration']))
```

Comment: with one caveat -- the variables['productionConfiguration'] needs to NOT have quotes around it.  you want

condition:   and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'),  eq('${{ configuration }}', variables['productionConfiguration']))

and not

condition:   and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'),  eq('${{ configuration }}', "variables['productionConfiguration']"))